# Como usar diferentes fontes no mesmo campo de Texto

Tags: java, android

EU peço uma ajuda, estou tentando contruir um programa simples que contenha um campo de texto (Edittext) e dois botões. 
A ideia é escrever um texto qualquer no meu campo de texto e em seguida se eu clicar no primeiro botão quero que o meu texto mude para itálico e se eu clicar no segundo botão o texto mude para Negrito(Bold).

Peço ajuda ai.

Vou postar os codigos:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp" 
    android:id="@+id/et1"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp" 
    android:id="@+id/italico"
    android:text="Itálico" 
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/negrito"
    android:text="Negrito"/>
```

E o codigo java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText t1;


Button b1, b2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     t1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.texto);
     b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.italico);
     b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.negrito);

     b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
     //Preciso tomar o texto no campo t1 e mudá lo para itálico
         }
     });
     b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             //Preciso tomar o texto no campo t1 e mudá lo para Negrito
         }
     });
}}
```

Agora eu quero construir um programa que contenha 3 campos de texto (Edittext) com os seguintes Id texto1, texto2 e texto3 respectivamente e um Botão com o id Take, onde o programa pede para digitar dois textos quaisquer nos campos texto1 e texto2 e ao clicar no botão Take, se faça uma busca dos textos que se encontram nos campos texto1 e texto2 e escreva ao mesmo tempo no campo texto3 mas eu preciso que no campo texto3 seja impresso o texto do campo texto1 em negrito e o texto do campo texto2 em itálico.

Veja os códigos:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/texto1"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/texto2"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/texto3"/>


<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/Take"
    android:text="Take"/>
```

e o código Java

@Override

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    t1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.texto1);
    t2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.texto1);
    t3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.texto1);


 b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Take);

    final Typeface boldTypeface = Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD); //negrito
    final Typeface italicTypeface = Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.ITALIC); //itálico

 b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {


     }
 });
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para mudar o estilo do texto, você necessita definir um [Typeface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface) e, a seguir, aplicá-lo ao componente desejado:

```
Typeface boldTypeface = Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD); //negrito
Typeface italicTypeface = Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.ITALIC); //itálico
```

Aplicando ao componente:

```
t1.setTypeface(boldTypeface);
t1.setTypeface(italicTypeface);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou correctamente

Comment: Marque a resposta como correta. Isso ajuda futuros usuários com dúvida semelhante à sua.

Comment: Agora surgiu me uma nova questão. Me ajude novamente. Vou editar a pergunta.

Comment: Me ajudem, já actualizei a minha pergunta